# React native webview iOS disable scrolling either horizontal or vertical direction

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I want to disable horizontal scrolling for one webview, but it seems there is no way to do that.
The closest i found is [`directionallockenabled`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#directionallockenabled), but it only disable scrolling in one direction in favor of the other direction.

`scrollEnabled = {false}` is too powerful to use.

Comment: what do you mean by "is too powerful to use"?

Comment: sorry what i meant it is like nuclear bomb, no scroll can be done.

Comment: where do you apply that property? Flatlist? But that's what you want, isn't it?